# ListView adapter onClickListener for list item update

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

**I know this is already been asked a lot of times. but after trying many solutions I can't implement it successfully.**

I am making a list with custom layout in it which contains several `View`s. One of the views is `ImageView` and I want it to change its icon whenever the user clicks on it.

ListAdapter class I used is as follows:

```
public class PetitionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomObject> objects;

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivsign;
    }

    public PetitionListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomObject> objects) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public CustomObject getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.petition_list_layout_beta, null);
            holder.ivsign = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivsign);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ivsign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView img = v.findViewById(R.id.ivsign);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_after_click);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Doing this, clickListener works, but instead of that particular imageview, it changes icon of many imageviews at random rows. I know its because of viewHolder. But how can I do this correctly?

*Also I had used :-*

> imgViewArray[position] = holder.textView1;

*inside "onListItemClickListener". Doing this it changes the icon at that position as I want, but after scrolling and getting back to that row again, it got changed to default icon again. I know this is because that row get recycled.*

Comment: Use the position from the dataset as you mentioned in your code to update the position then `notify` the adapter about the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you got this problem. Why? because when list view was scrolled, all your `convert view`s were reused and each `convertView` was used to display another `CustomObject`. That means if you changed your first-row image, after scrolling, the row which reused the `first-row convertView` showed the `image` as `clicked row`. So, how to solve it? You have to save the position of item in your `CustomObject`, something like:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.petition_list_layout_beta, null);
        holder.ivsign = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivsign);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final CustomObject object = listCustomObject.get(position);
    holder.ivsign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_after_click);
            object.saveResourceId(R.drawable.icon_after_click); // save your resource to use after scrolling.
        }
    });
    // display resouce base on what's saved or display default image.
    holder.ivSign.setImageResource(object.getSavedResourceId()); 
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It worked !. Please check the CustomObject class if I have done it right? `public class CustomObject {
    private int resId = R.drawable.ic_sign;
    public CustomObject() {}

    
    public String getProp9() {
        return prop9;
    }

    public void saveResourceId(int rid) { this.resId = rid; }

    public int getSavedResourceId() { return resId; }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from your `onClickListener`. You are setting it for the `ImageView` in your `ViewHolder`, and then inside the `onClick` method you do `v.findViewById`.

What you should do is

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivsign);
```

And then

```
img.setOnClickListener(.......);
```

This works for me, so let me know if you are having any problems implementing.

Comment: Still problem is same i.e. changes random imageView icons.

Answer (score 0):

That's not good practice. In `OnItemClick` you should change the list of objects that is used by the list, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. In `getView(...)` you should simply make the listView reflect the values from the list.
This way, when the list is refreshed, the states of the views remain the same.

Comment: Isn't refreshing list shows the data again from starting (from 1st row) ? Actually I want icon change when user click imageView and then continues scrolling (just like as clicking "Like" button on facebook). And if the answer in "no" then I am definitely gonna use it.